# Kiba ETL and Faraday request

Tags: ruby, etl, kiba-etl

I am working on a project that has the CDC concept. It reads from a database changes and push events to a rabbitmq queue (it uses debezium).

After that I am using KibaETL to process the event message consuming from that queue.

KibaETL has the 3 main process

- source (I get from rabbitmq queue and works properly)
- transform (I parse the json message and I am trying to make an external API to retrieve some additional data.
- destination (I am testing saving to local file)

The strange part is. When I call faraday it silently quit the kiba etl pipeline. It doesnt show any error....

Here goes the snippet of my transform class.

```
#frozen_string_literal: true

require 'faraday'
require 'faraday/net_http'
require 'json'
require 'kiba'

class RetrieveJobDataTransform
  def process(row)
    puts "\t[transform] Retrieve Job Information by UUID - job_uuid: #{row}"
    raise ArgumentError, 'row cannot be nil' if row.nil?

    job_uuid = row.dig(:after_data, 'job_uuid')
    
    api_result = make_api_call(job_uuid)

    transformed_data = transform_data(row, api_result)

    transformed_data
  end

  private

  def make_api_call(job_uuid)    
    
    conn = create_connection('https://url.com')    
    
    **# before conn.get call, it shows output properly**
    response = conn.get("api/jobs/#{job_uuid}")
    **# here it doesnt show any output when I was debugging**

    if response.success?
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def transform_data(row, api_result)
    row = api_result
  end

  def create_connection(api_url)
    Faraday.new(api_url) do |f|
      f.headers['x-api-key'] = 'api key'
      f.response :json 
      f.adapter :net_http 
      f.options.timeout = 120
    end
  end
end
```

And the main class that is called to process ETL

```
job = Kiba.parse do
  source KibaSource, bunny_adapter, queue_name

  transform ParseMessageTransform
  transform ValidateMessageTransform

  **#This is the class that silently quit with no error or warnings**
  transform RetrieveJobDataTransform 
  
  destination KibaDestination
end

puts '# job started - Running Kiba job... '
Kiba.run(job)
```

The strange behaviour is that if I enter 'irb' and add that class code and call it without being inside kiba etl pipeline, it works with no error.

Any one could give me any advice? I am stuck in this problem with no ideias how to go through it.

Thanks in advance

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would be fairly surprised if it was actually Kiba related (even if you can get the thing working in IRB), due to how Kiba works. But I would love to rule this out.

Would you be willing to create the smallest possible reproduction (maybe with a single-file Bundler config https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_in_a_single_file_ruby_script.html), in which you would "stub" out the source and the destination?

Weird things could be happening potentially because you are recreating Faraday connections for each and every row.

I would also probably try to use another HTTP client e.g. HTTParty for the calls you are making. There is a chance that some conflict could occur for some reason between your calls and the RabbitMQ calls, maybe!

Happy to help further, if you can post the smallest repro via gist.github.com I will definitely be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

> source KibaSource, bunny_adapter, queue_name

Hello!  Thank you for the help! I created a stub for source and it worked fine. So there's some conflict with the rabbitMQ calls. I think is due to the thread that rabbit creates inside when consuming events and its context.

I am trying to understand what's going on KibaSource using rabbitmq consumers to avoid the error.

Comment: remove unnecessary errors